# Traits with default methods that depend on a bound of an associated type

Tags: rust, associated-types

I can't figure out a way to make this code compile with `--cfg on_trait`:

```
trait DigitCollection: Sized {
    type Iter: Iterator<Item = u8>;
    fn digit_iter(self) -> Self::Iter;

    #[cfg(on_trait)]
    fn digit_sum(self) -> u32 {
        self.digit_iter()
            .map(|digit: u8| digit as u32)
            .fold(0, |sum, digit| sum + digit)
    }
}

#[cfg(not(on_trait))]
fn digit_sum<T: DigitCollection>(collection: T) -> u32 {
    collection.digit_iter()
        .map(|digit: u8| digit as u32)
        .fold(0, |sum, digit| sum + digit)
}

fn main() {
}
```

With `on_trait` this fails with:

```
trait.rs:7:14: 7:26 error: type annotations required: cannot resolve `<<Self as DigitCollection>::Iter as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == u8` [E0284]
trait.rs:7         self.digit_iter()
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Without `on_trait`, it compiles just fine. Note that the `not(on_trait)` variant only differs by the fact that it is a free function instead of a default method.

---

Edit: I opened an issue on this: [rust-lang/rust#22036](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22036)

Comment: There are still a number of holes in associated types where things that should be legal don’t compile. This looks like it is one of them.

Comment: Incidentally, `fn digit_iter(self) -> Self::Iter;` works, no need for the `<Self as DigitCollection>`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will open an issue, in case this isn't a known problem (I wasn't able to find any open issue on this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code now compiles as desired:

```
trait DigitCollection: Sized {
    type Iter: Iterator<Item = u8>;
    fn digit_iter(self) -> Self::Iter;

    fn digit_sum(self) -> u32 {
        self.digit_iter()
            .map(|digit: u8| digit as u32)
            .fold(0, |sum, digit| sum + digit)
    }
}

fn main() {}
```